# How to set hadoop configuration values from pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

The Scala version of SparkContext has the property

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration
```

I have successfully used that to set Hadoop properties (in Scala)

e.g.

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("my.mapreduce.setting","someVal")
```

However the python version of SparkContext lacks that accessor. Is there any way to set Hadoop configuration values into the Hadoop Configuration used by the PySpark context?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('my.mapreduce.setting', 'someVal')
```

should work

Comment: This solution also applies to anyone trying to get their AWS AccessKeyId/SecretAccessKey to be accepted when using s3n:// addresses.
`sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId','<access_key_id>')`

Comment: As of today, seems _jsc is no longer available.

Comment: I've filed [SPARK-33436](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33436) to track adding `hadoopConfiguration` directly to the PySpark API, so that using `._jsc` is no longer necessary.

Comment: I couldn't set `fs.defaultFS` with this solution. It gives me error `An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get. : java.lang.NullPointerException`. Is it because it's unsupported property to set?

Comment: [added answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751442/496289) for newer versions of spark after `_jsc` is removed.

Answer (score 5):

You can set any Hadoop properties using the `--conf` parameter while submitting the job.

```
--conf "spark.hadoop.fs.mapr.trace=debug"
```

Source: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala#L105

Answer (score 4):

I looked into the PySpark source code (***context.py***)  and there is not a direct equivalent. Instead some specific methods support sending in a  map of (key,value) pairs:

```py
fileLines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile('dev/*', 
'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
conf={'mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive':'true'}
).count()
```