# reading a s3 file with s3a format using pyspark - High

Tags: pyspark

```
#
# Some constants
#
aws_profile = "your_profile"
aws_region = "your_region"
s3_bucket = "your_bucket"

# 
# Reading environment variables from aws credential file 
#
import os
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.expanduser("~/.aws/credentials"))

access_id = config.get(aws_profile, "aws_access_key_id") 
access_key = config.get(aws_profile, "aws_secret_access_key") 

# 
# Configuring pyspark
#

# see https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/127#issuecomment-214594895 
# and https://github.com/radanalyticsio/pyspark-s3-notebook/blob/master/s3-source-example.ipynb
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell"

# If this doesn't work you might have to delete your ~/.ivy2 directory to reset your package cache.
# (see https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/244#issuecomment-239950148)
import pyspark
sc=pyspark.SparkContext()
# see https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/298#issuecomment-271834485
sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844631/how-to-set-hadoop-configuration-values-from-pyspark
hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454117/how-do-you-use-s3a-with-spark-2-1-0-on-aws-us-east-2
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_id)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", access_key)

# see http://blog.encomiabile.it/2015/10/29/apache-spark-amazon-s3-and-apache-mesos/
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.connection.maximum", "100000")

# see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3." + aws_region + ".amazonaws.com")

#
# Downloading the parquet file
#
sql=pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)
path = s3_bucket + "your_path"
dataS3=sql.read.parquet("s3://" + path)
```

*Even have tried to write a file thinking that my directory pointing was not correct and if the file write is successful, could pin point the path where it is pointing now but still no progress and say no path exists.
If you please could guide us in this regard, it would really be helpful. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Can you please post the response you are getting back from s3?

Comment: If you want someones help you need to post as much information as possible, code, error messages, etc.